# WPF use override Property in inherit class in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a little problem and can´t find any solution. Maybe it is an issue in Visual Studio.

I have created a new class that is inherited from Image. I then override the Source property.

```
class GifImage : Image
{
     public new ImageSource Source
     {
         get { return base.Source; } 
         set
         {
             MesssageBox("new source property");
             base.Source = value;
         } 
     }
}
```

If I set Source in code

```
GifImage gifImage = new GifImage();
gifImage.Source = gifimage2;
```

Then the Source will be correctly set to GifImage and the MessageBox will be shown.

But if I set Source in the Xaml-Code:

```
<my1:GifImage Stretch="Uniform" Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/Preloader.gif" />
```

Then the Source property of the Image will be set and the MessageBox won´t be shown.

My idea was to set the System.ComponentModel.Browsable-Attribute, thinking that maybe the property in the inherit GifImage class is not visible in Visual Studio and it is using the source property of the parent class.

```
[Browsable(true)]
public new ImageSource Source
```

But this is still not working.

Has somebody had the same problem or/and the solution for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not able to override a DependencyProperty in that manner in WPF.

As the Source property on an Image is a DependencyProperty, when the value is assigned in XAML (and other places) it's value is set using

```
DependencyObject.SetValue(SourceProperty, value)
```

One possible solution is to override the metadata of the DependencyProperty and add change listener, e.g.

```
    static GifImage()
    {
        SourceProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(GifImage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(SourcePropertyChanged)));

    }

    private static void SourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox("new source property");
    }
```

or alternativly using the DependencyPropertyDescriptor

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Image.SourceProperty, typeof(Image));
if (dpd != null)
{
   dpd.AddValueChanged(tb, delegate
   {
       MessageBox("new source property");
   });
}
```

Comment: For the first solution I get an ArgumentException, that the PropertyMetadata is still registered by type "Image"

Comment: I found the fault
In SourceProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Image), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(SourcePropertyChanged)));
I have to use the typeof of my control that will override it. Here typeof(GifImage)

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working. I was just about to make a small app to figure out what I had done wrong. I will update answer to change the type.