# Override property in derived class

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, inheritance, overriding

I have asked a similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368095/override-a-property-defined-in-base-class)  before but this time its a little extended. What I had already asked was to override `SomeProperty` in the derived class for which the answer was using the 'new' operator.

But now I am again in the same scenario but,

> this time I have to execute a default behaviour in the base class
>   while setting the `SomeProperty` in the derived class.

I have to force the user who is deriving from my base class to execute a set of code in base class while setting the `SomeProperty` in the derived class. I have already tried with Template Pattern but I need to bind this to a Custom Control in my Windows Phone Control Library. So my base class cannot be a `abstract` class. So I cannot specify a common functionality in the base class and make sure that the functionality is enforced while the variable is set in the derived class.

Is there any other way I could enforce this code (or kind of rule) executes in the base class while setting the property in the derived class?

Edit:
  I should also mention that the person who is deriving from the base class is not expected to call the specific behaviour in base class. I need to force the invocation.

```
   +---------------+
   | UIElement     |
   |---------------|                            +----------------------+
   | ...           |                            | My Windows Application
   | SomePropert{} |                            |----------------------|
   | //Force to    |<---+                       |+--------------------+|
   | //to xcute this code                       ||MyUserControl       ||
   +---------------+    |                       ||--------------------||
         +--------------+-----+                 ||                    ||
         |FrameWorkElement    |                 |+--------------------+|
         |--------------------|                 |//Want to use         |
         |    ...             |<-+              |// SomeProperty;      |
         +--------------------+  |              |                      |
                     +-----------+-+            |                      |
                     |Control      |            |                      |
                     |-------------|            +----------------------+
                     |  ...        |<---+
                     +-------------+    |
                            +-----------+---+
                            | UserControl   |
                            |---------------|<---+
                            |  ...          |    |
                            +---------------+    |
                                      +----------+-------+
                                      | MyUserControl    |
                                      |------------------|
                                      | SomeProperty{}   |
                                      | //Want to override
                                      | //Setting this here|
                                      |//should make sure|
                                      |//base class code |
                                      |//gets executed   |
                                      +------------------+
```

Comment: You can use `new` on a method the same as you can on a property. You could also use a bit of reflection to reach inside the base class and poke the members. Using reflection and caching delegates would be my recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use the `base` keyword to ensure that the original method is executed as well. For example,

```
public new void Method()
{ 
    DoMyCustomStuff();
    base.Method();
}
```

Comment: Actually I cannot expect the user deriving from the base class to call it explicitly. I need to call it implicitly (force) , the behaviour in the base class.